# get current value of column query builder laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel and I want to update via query builder

here is my query

```
DB::table('cart_product')->where([['cart_id', '=', $cart->id], ['product_id', '=', $productId]])->update(['quantity' => $quantity, 'total_price' => $productPrice * $quantity, 'specification_price' => $currentSpecification_price* $quantity]);
```

so I want to multiply $quantity with current value of this column
How can I access to $currentSpecification_price I mean current value of column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DB::raw('column_name')` to get the current column value like this:

```php
DB::table('cart_product')
   ->where([['cart_id', '=', $cart->id], ['product_id', '=', $productId]])
   ->update(['quantity' => $quantity, 
             'total_price' => $productPrice * $quantity, 
             'specification_price' => DB::raw('specification_price') * $quantity]);
```

Comment: This doesn;t work for me: Unsupported operand types: Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression * int